# How to know the positivity of a given polynomial

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, algebraic-geometry, operator-theory, operator-algebras

Let $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{(2p+1)(2p+2)}x^{2p}+\sum\limits_{i=1}^{2p}\binom{2p+1}{i}\dfrac{1}{i+1}x^{i-1}.$ How do you know about the positivity of the $f(x)$? I am trying to induction on $p$ as well as combine the term $1,x, x^2$ and $1,x^3, x^6$, etc as well as combine the terms $1,x,x^2$ and $x^2, x^3, x^4$, etc to get the sum of squares. However, it is hard to control when the coefficient depends on the binomial with $p$. I also tried to use Sturm theorem as well as Eneström's theorem to determine its zeros points and from there to see the positivity but I am not successful either. It would be great if someone can give me some help. Thanks.

Comment: What precisely do you mean by "positivity"? The first several instances, numerically, all take negative values for particular negative values of $x$; meanwhile, it's obvious that $f(x)$ is positive for positive values of $x$.

Comment: Hi @GregMartin, thank you for your answer. I would like to have a rigorous argument for that. I also tried with some values and it is positive + the highest order is $2p$. So, I am pretty sure that it is positive but I don't know how to derive it rigorously. Actually, I want to prove that it can be bounded be low by $\delta\times(x^{2p}+x^{2(p-1)}+\cdots+x+1)$ with $\delta$ is a small constant, or simply $\delta(x^{2p}+1)$.

Comment: Again, what do you mean by “positivity”? For which values of $x$? As Greg noted above, $f(x)$ does *not* appear to be positive if $x$ is allowed to be negative. And, if $x$ is required to be positive, then it’s obvious that $f(x)$ is too, I mean there aren’t any minus signs in the definition of $f$.

Comment: @JakeLevinson: Thank you very much. I will check it back later.